# Generating tables of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, beginner

I have this code and this works fine but I think it's too lengthy. I want to know if there can be a less lengthy code. I've heard from people that lengthy code is often not considered good.

```
<html>
<head><title>Table</title></head> 
<body>
<form method = "Post" action = "Table.php" > 
Enter a number between 2 and 20 to see its tables: 
<input type = "text" name = "number" /> 
<input type = "hidden" value = "true" name = "checker" /> 
</form> 
<?PHP 
if ( isset($_POST['checker'])) { 
$number = $_POST['number']; 
switch ($number) { 
case 2: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 3: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 4: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 5: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 6: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 7: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 8: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 9: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
case 10: 
for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <= 10 ; $counter++ ) {
$temp = $number * $counter ; 
echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
} 
break;
default:
echo "Please enter a number between 2 and 10"; 
} 
} 
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: State only code-purpose in title

Comment: I'm new at stackoverflow so don't know how to ask a question. Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: Here, on CodeReview, we'd like you to state what your code is supposed to do, and to have a descriptive title, telling what your code does, not what you want reviewed :)

Comment: I suggest `Generating tables of numbers in PHP` as the title

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already gave in the [wrong placed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767872/any-better-code-to-replace-mine#comment53376506_32767872), anyway here is my solution: [codepad.viper-7.com/zTLliA](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zTLliA)

Copy&paste is never a good idea.

```
if (isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number']) && (($_POST['number'] > 0) && ($_POST['number'] <= 20))) { 
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter <=10; $counter++ ) {
        $temp = $number * $counter ;
        echo "$number x $counter = $temp<br />"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "Please enter a number between 1 and 20"; 
}
```

A single `for` is enough. In the `if` statement we check if the `$_POST['number']` exists, if it's actually a number and if it is between 1 and 20.

Comment: Please include code in question and **explain the improvements** we mainly improve coders, code only incidentally.

Comment: @Caridorc I thought it was quite self explanating, by the way I have **improved the answer**. Hope it helps, have a nice day.

Comment: _A single for is enough. In the if statement we check if the $POST_['number'] exists, if it's actually a number and if it is between 1 and 20._ <- that is an explanation +1 and welcome to Codereview